# How can I tell where mongoDB is storing data? (its not in the default /data/db!)

Tags: mongodb, directory, database

My host came with a mongodb instance and there is no /db directory so now I am wondering what I can do to find out where the data is actually being stored.

Comment: There is a more recent question on this which has a better answer: ["What is the default database path for mongodb?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247474/how-can-i-tell-where-mongodb-is-storing-data-its-not-in-db). The data path will either be the default of `/data/db` (if no config file is being used) or discoverable via `db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts").parsed.dbpath`.

Comment: on OSX, mongo 3.0.4, i had to use "db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts").parsed.storage.dbPath"

Comment: @Stennie your comment helped me (I'm on Windows so I'm using Robomongo), but your question-link points at this question, not at your intended target -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12738557/112764 -- and in 3.x, it's actually `db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts").parsed.storage.dbpath`

Comment: @NateJ Thanks! The [answer on the related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12738557/112764) has examples for MongoDB 2.6+ as well as the older form in <= 2.4. There's also a shell helper you can use instead of  remembering to change to the `admin` database or using `adminCommand`: `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.storage.dbPath` (MongoDB 2.6+).

Answer (score 167, accepted):

`mongod` defaults the database location to `/data/db/`.

If you run `ps -xa | grep mongod` and you don't see a `--dbpath` which explicitly tells `mongod` to look at that parameter for the db location and you don't have a `dbpath` in your `mongodb.conf`, then the default location will be: `/data/db/` and you should look there.

Comment: @user2384994 mine was located at `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: Did not see the path, but `/usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`. Took the dbpatch from the config.

Comment: Check `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`(config file) and `/usr/local/var/mongodb` (database location) as well. On some systems, these will be the defaults.

Comment: Well this one SHOULD print the current path precisely for all mongodb version https://stackoverflow.com/a/52036070/248616

Comment: i.e. the `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`

Comment: can someone help me with Windows, please? How do I know where my data path is in Windows 10?

Answer (score 65):

What does your configuration file say?

```
$ grep dbpath /etc/mongodb.conf
```

If it is not correct, try this, your database files will be present on the list:

```
$ sudo lsof -p `ps aux | grep mongodb | head -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 2` | grep REG
```

It's `/var/lib/mongodb/*` on my default installation (Ubuntu 11.04).

Note that there is also a `/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock` file holding `mongod` PID for convenience, however it is located in the data directory - which we are looking for...

Comment: No /var/lib directory on this server and those two commands do not work (first one cannot find /etc/mongodb.conf second one unrecognized lsof)

Comment: Maybe you should add infos for your host. Doesn't seem to be an Ubuntu like distro.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 mongodb v3.4.10, it is `$ grep dbPath /etc/mongod.conf`

Answer (score 55):

I find `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` the most robust way to find actual path if you can connect to the server. The "parsed.storage.dbPath" contains the path your server is currently using and is available both when it's taken from the config or from the command line arguments.

Also in my case it was important to make sure that the config value reflects the actual value (i.e. config didn't change after the last restart), which isn't guaranteed by the solutions offered here.

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
```

Example output:

```
{
    "argv" : [ 
        // --
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "config" : "/your-config",
        "storage" : {
            "dbPath" : "/your/actual/db/path",
            // --
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but is there a way to do it on mongocxx?

Comment: @Dariusz, as far as I understand it, it's just a C++ driver. Are you unable to connect to mongo directly via its native client?

Comment: This should have been the correct answer! It always shows what the db sees

Answer (score 36):

In the newer version of mongodb v2.6.4 try:

```
grep dbpath /etc/mongod.conf
```

It will give you something like this:

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
```

And that is where it stores the data.

Comment: Mine was here also. For people that wanted to find this directory to check file sizes: `du -sh * | sort -hr`

Answer (score 32):

While this question asks about Linux/Unix instances of Mongo, it's one of the first search results regardless of the operating system used, so for future Windows users that find this:

If MongoDB is set up as a Windows Service in the default manner, you can usually find it by looking at the 'Path to executable' entry in the MongoDB Service's Properties:

[image: Properties Window showing 'Path to Executable' option]

Comment: It is not that obvious, but questions is for *nix os

Comment: @st78 I know, but it's still one of the first Google results when searching for the location in Windows, which is why I left an answer addressing the Windows path (once I figured it out) for the people like me who stumble across it.

Answer (score 15):

From my experience the default location is `/var/lib/mongodb` after I do

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: I can confirm this for Linux Mint 17.3 users.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, the default directory where the mongod instance stores its data is

`/data/db` on Linux and OS X,

`\data\db` on Windows

To check the same, you can look for **dbPath** settings in [mongodb configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file).

- On Linux, the location is  `/etc/mongod.conf`, if you have used package manager to install MongoDB.
  Run the following command to check the specified directory:

  ```
  grep dbpath /etc/mongodb.conf
  ```
- On Windows, the location is `<install directory>/bin/mongod.cfg`. Open **mongod.cfg** file and check for **dbPath** option.
- On macOS, the location is `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` when installing from MongoDB’s official Homebrew tap.

---

The default **mongod.conf** configuration file included with package manager installations uses the following platform-specific default values for [`storage.dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath):

```
+--------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+
|         Platform         | Package Manager | Default storage.dbPath |
+--------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+
| RHEL / CentOS and Amazon | yum             | /var/lib/mongo         |
| SUSE                     | zypper          | /var/lib/mongo         |
| Ubuntu and Debian        | apt             | /var/lib/mongodb       |
| macOS                    | brew            | /usr/local/var/mongodb |
+--------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+
```

The [`storage.dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) setting in the configuration file is available only for [`mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod).

The Linux package init scripts do not expect `storage.dbPath` to change from the defaults. If you use the Linux packages and change `storage.dbPath`, you will have to use your own init scripts and disable the built-in scripts.

[Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options)

Comment: Actually this should be the top-answer! The default `dbPath` are different to the dbPath in pre-installed `mongod.cfg` config files. Many people don't recognize it.

Answer (score 9):

I found mine here on a OSX system
/usr/local/var/mongodb

Comment: This is true for Homebrew users

Comment: The question is "How can I find" the mongodb data storage location. not just the path for a specific user or platform.

Answer (score 7):

For windows Go inside MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin folder and open mongod.cfg file in any text editor. Then locate the line that specifies the dbPath param. The line looks something similar

> dbPath: D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data

Answer (score 4):

On MongoDB 4.4+ and on CentOS 8, I found the path by running:

```
grep dbPath /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it just by poking around in `/var/db`.  Thanks for the help though--I am sure these answers apply to other systems (e.g. Ubuntu) and will help others!

Answer (score 2):

When you start it up it shows you.  But I don't know if it is something you can do or not on your host.  If you have access to the command line and can restart the service, you will get something like:

```
    2016-11-15T12:57:09.182-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
 MongoDB starting : pid=16448 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\
```

Answer (score 2):

If you could somehow locate mongod.log and the do a grep over it

```
grep dbpath mongod.log
```

The value for dbpath is the data location for mongodb!! 
All the best :)