# What is the default database path for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I got an error about `dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist`, but `/etc/mongodb.conf` named it `dbpath = /var/lib/mongodb.`

So, which is the default dbpath for MongoDB?

Answer (score 85):

The default dbpath for mongodb is `/data/db`.

There is no default config file, so you will either need to specify this when starting `mongod` with:

```
 mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

.. or use a packaged install of MongoDB (such as for [Redhat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) or [Debian/Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/)) which will include a config file path in the service definition.

Note: to check the dbpath and command-line options for a running `mongod`, connect via the `mongo` shell and run:

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
```

In particular, if a custom `dbpath` is set it will be the value of:

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.dbpath           // MongoDB 2.4 and older
db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.storage.dbPath   // MongoDB 2.6+
```

Comment: To get the path to the database from the mongo shell is, as of 2.6.1:     db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.storage.dbPath

Answer (score 24):

I have version 2.0.7 installed on Ubuntu and it defaulted to `/var/lib/mongodb/` and that is also what was placed into my `/etc/mongodb.conf` file.

Comment: why the book `mongodb:the definitive guide` said that it defaulted to `/data/db`? I don't know why .

Comment: This could be a factor of how the distribution package was built.  I installed my copy using `apt-get`.  How did you install your copy?  Are you still getting the error about dbpath not existing?

Answer (score 15):

For a Windows machine start the `mongod` process by specifying the dbpath:

```
mongod --dbpath \mongodb\data
```

Reference: [Manage `mongod` Processes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

Comment: This answer also applicable to Linux

Answer (score 13):

The `dbPath` in Mongo can be confusing. If you don't specify the `dbPath` at all (neither as command line parameter nor in `mongod.conf` file) then it defaults to

- `/data/db` on Linux and macOS
- `\data\db` on Windows (on current drive)

However, the **default** `mongod.conf` files which comes along the installation and which is used when you start mongod as a service (e.g. `systemctl start mongod`) uses these ones:

| Platform | Package Manager | Default `storage.dbPath` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RHEL / CentOS and Amazon | yum | `/var/lib/mongo` |
| SUSE | zypper | `/var/lib/mongo` |
| Ubuntu and Debian | apt | `/var/lib/mongodb` |
| macOS | brew | `/usr/local/var/mongodb` |
| Windows | MSI | `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\{release}\data\` |

So, you must carefully check what you are using.

See [Run-time Database Configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/configuration/)

Comment: The default `mongo` docker image also defaults to `/data/db` as it is started without configuration file by default.

Answer (score 10):

I depends on the version and the distro.

For example the default download pre-2.2 from the MongoDB site uses: `/data/db` but the Ubuntu install at one point used to use: `var/lib/mongodb`.

I think these have been standardised now so that 2.2+ will only use `data/db` whether it comes from direct download on the site or from the repos.

Comment: The difference in the distros is based on the packaging & service definition.  Start `mongod` without any parameters and you will get a default dbpath of `/data/db` (the only hardcoded default).

Comment: I am using Debain and the default went to var/lib/mongodb as well

Answer (score 5):

The Windows x64 installer shows the a path in the installer UI/wizard.

You can confirm which path it used later, by opening your `mongod.cfg` file. My `mongod.cfg` was located here `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg` (change for your version of MongoDB!

When I opened my `mongd.cfg` I found this line, showing the default db path:

```
dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data
```

However, this caused an error when trying to run `mongod`, which was still expecting to find `C:\data\db`:

`2019-05-05T09:32:36.084-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating`

You could pass `mongod` a `--dbpath=...` parameter. In my case:

```
mongod --dbpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data"
```