# Location of the mongodb database on mac

Tags: macos, mongodb, osx-lion

I am kind of new to mac as well as mongodb.

I have a weird doubt, accessing the database created using mongodb on mac?

I know, in windows there is a folder called c:\data\db, where my database files are stored.

How and where in mac, the database is stored.

I remember doing something like

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

to create such a folder on mac, but I didn't find any database file in this folder, though i created a database.

Where are the database files saved on mac?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Be aware of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043090/3027266

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The default data directory for MongoDB is `/data/db`.

This can be overridden by a [`dbpath` option](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-SpecifyingaDataDirectory) specified on the command line or in a configuration file.

If you install MongoDB via a [package manager](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#installing-with-package-management) such as Homebrew or MacPorts these installs typically create a default data directory other than /data/db and set the dbpath in a configuration file.

If a dbpath was provided to `mongod` on startup you can check the value in the `mongo` shell:

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
```

You would see a value like:

```
"parsed" : {
    "dbpath" : "/usr/local/data"
},
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that your `mongod` server does not have to run as the `root` user.  You do need to ensure that your data directory permissions include read/write access for the user account the `mongod` server is using.

Comment: When I input getCommandLineOpts(), I get something like `ReferenceError: getCommandLineOpts is not defined (shell):1´. Any help??

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  You should be able to check that with `db.serverStatus().version`.  I believe the shell helper for `getCommandLineOpts()` was added in MongoDB 2.0.  You could also try: `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1})`.

Comment: I use version 2.2.2, when i tried `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1})` I got something like `{ "argv" : [ "./bin/mongod" ], "parsed" : { }, "ok" : 1 }` Does that mean, my database directory is not set??

Comment: I got it mate, I created a folder called data in the root and a subfolder db. Now it's showing the path. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yes, if you don't see an entry for `dbpath` under the `parsed` config options the default path of `/data/db` is being used.

Comment: @Stennie so your suggestion worked. `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1})` Anyone care to edit this answer to make it more visible?

Comment: @kgpdeveloper: updated with even shorter syntax: db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")

Answer (score 263):

If MongoDB is installed on macOS via Homebrew, the default data directory depends on the type of processor in the system.

|  | Intel Processor | Apple Silicon Processor (M1, M2, etc) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data Directory | `/usr/local/var/mongodb` | `/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb` |
| Configuration file | `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` | `/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf` |
| Log directory | `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb` | `/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb` |

Run `brew --prefix` to see where Homebrew installed these files.

See the [MongoDB "Install on macOS"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) documentation for additional details.

Comment: I was looking for some light in the darkness by checking the formula at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb thanks.

Comment: In newer versions of Homebrew, it's `/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb`.

Comment: Thanks @JW. I updated the answer to include what I found in the MongoDB docs. Let me know if you see anything else that needs updating.

Answer (score 165):

Thanks @Mark, I keep forgetting this again and again.
After installing MongoDB with Homebrew:

- The databases are stored in the **/usr/local/var/mongodb/** directory
- The mongod.conf file is here: **/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf**
- The mongo logs can be found at **/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/**
- The mongo binaries are here: **/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/[version]/bin**

Comment: When i check **/usr/local/var/mongodb/**, the directory is empty. And no, i haven't changed mongoldb's default dbpath. Can you help me in finding the database file?

Comment: Add a symbolic link for it: sudo ln -s /usr/local/var/mongodb /data/db

Comment: I don't seem to have a folder `etc` in `/usr/local/`. Where are the config files located or how can I find out lol?

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, with version 3.4.2

to run it (if you installed it with homebrew) run the process like this:

```
$ mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Comment: This solution solved my issue after upgrading to v4.2.5 via Homebrew.

Answer (score 10):

I have just installed **mongodb 3.4** with *homebrew*.(brew install mongodb) 
It looks for **/data/db** by default.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

[image: Here is the output of mongod execution.]

Comment: This is if you start `mongod` directly from the terminal. If you use `brew services start mongodb`, the process will use the config file at `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` which, in turn, specifies a `dbPath` of `/usr/local/var/mongodb`

Comment: Thanks @Molomby for the contribution. I wasn't started that way, I didn't even know that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Env**: macOS Mojave 10.14.4

**Install**: homebrew

**Location**:`/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/4.0.3_1`

**Note** :If update version by
`brew upgrade mongo`,the folder `4.0.4_1` will be removed and replace with the new version folder