# Can start MongoDB properly on Mac

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, compass, mongodb-compass

I wasn't able to start MongoDB on my new Mac properly..

I installed everything new but Compass doesn't find anything.

First I do

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

It seems to work

```
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
```

But when I check with

```
brew services list
```

I get

```
Name              Status  User       Plist
mongodb-community error   <UserName> /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Has someone an idea?

I use macOS Big Sur 11.6, Intel i7

Comment: Did you check the log file?

Comment: Recent Mac upgrades will not allow user files at the root of the system filesystem.  Some MongoDB deployments assume the data directory is `/data`.  These systems will not start as they cannot write to the directory `/data`.  If this is your condition, you must configure the path to a writeable path by the user starting the `mongod` process.  As described by Wernfried, check the log files.  For Homebrew, I believe the default logs are at `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/`, and I believe the default configuration file is `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827915/location-of-the-mongodb-database-on-mac/13828103

Comment: thanks first @WernfriedDomscheit and @barrypicker so much! So plan is to change `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` right? And reset the data directory from `/data` to `/Users/<myUserName>/Documents/databases/mongodb` for example? I'm a bit confused by the `mongo.log` and didn't found the `/data` path. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `systemLog:`
`  destination: file`
`  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`
`  logAppend: true`
`storage:`
`  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb`
`net:`
 ` bindIp: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: I changed now the `mongod.conf` with `storage: dbPath: /Users/<UserName>/data` .. but still same errors :/ @WernfriedDomscheit and @barrypicker any more hints?

Comment: What do you see in `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`? Please edit your question and put additional information there instead of a comment.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit when I do `open /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` in the terminal I get an error message even if I open the terminal as an admin.. error message is
`The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10826 "kLSNoLaunchPermissionErr: User doesn't have permission to launch the app (managed networks)" UserInfo=...`

Comment: full error message here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69664429/error-when-trying-to-checkmongodb-log-file

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was trying so many things now, but in the end the solution was quite simple:

Just to be sure update Homebrew

```
brew update
```

Install / reinstall / update MongoDB if needed

```
brew install mongodb
```

After downloading Mongo, create the “db” directory

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

Make sure you have the right permissions by running

```
> sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

And here we go!

As written here: [Read-only file system when attempting mkdir /data/db on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034955/read-only-file-system-when-attempting-mkdir-data-db-on-mac)

Mac does not allow to write the root folder.
So MongoDB is not able to use that folder properly.

You can change to a writable directory with:

```
mongod --dbpath=/Users/user/data/db
```

Fixed!