# Trying to run a replica set locally on mac with homebrew and run-rs

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, replicaset

I have mongo setup with homebrew.

```
$ brew services start mongodb-community
$ mongosh
```

I can see my DBs in mongo compass.

[image]

I want to run this DB but in a replica set. But I can't figure out how.

I tried using the [run-rs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-rs) package. But it didn't work.

I installed the package.

```
$ npm install run-rs -g
```

Then I ran `run-rs,` but it failed:

```
$ run-rs --mongod
Purging database...
Running 'mongod' [ 27017, 27018, 27019 ]
Starting replica set...
Error: failed to start mongod with options [
  '--port=27017',
  '--dbpath=/Users/projectpath/backend/data/27017',
  '--bind_ip=localhost',
  '--replSet=rs'
]
```

So then, I stopped MongoDB.

```
$ brew services stop mongodb-community
```

I ran `run-rs` again.

```
$ run-rs --mongod
Purging database...
Running 'mongod' [ 27017, 27018, 27019 ]
Starting replica set...
Started replica set on "mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019?replicaSet=rs"
Connected to oplog
(node:28395) [MONGODB DRIVER] DeprecationWarning: collection.find option [oplogReplay] is deprecated and will be removed in a later version.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

But this created a `data` folder with many files in my project directory. I don't want a bunch of project files in my directory. Are these files expected? If so, where should these files go? How do I get them into the correct directory? How come it's not behaving like my other mongo setup?

Now all the DBs I had before in mongo compass are gone. I can get back to them if I kill all mongo processes

```
$ ps wuax | grep mongo

$ kill (pid number)
```

and run:

```
$ brew services start mongodb-community
```

But How can I get my regular mongo community to use a replica set? Why are my mongo DBs gone when I run `run-rs`? And why does `run-rs` put many files in my project directory?

Am I missing how this is supposed to work?

**UPDATE**

I tried to add the homebrew path.

```
$ run-rs 5.0.6 --dbpath '/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb'
```

The data folder isn't added to my project now. But my old DBs shown in the first image are not in Mongo Compass anymore. Now when I switch to `brew services start mongodb-community` all my dev databases seemed to be removed.

Comment: Did you read the run-rs instructions? "_By default, run-rs will store data files in a directory named 'data'. To specify a dbPath for run-rs to use as a data directory, use the --dbpath option._"

Comment: yea had I also tried the command with the dbpath option and it still seemed to create files in my project directory and not connect to my original DB. I probably should have included that in the OP. Maybe the problem was the path I used mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017. Maybe it's supposed to be the path homebrew uses?

Comment: I think this might be the path I need `/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827915/location-of-the-mongodb-database-on-mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that once you get `run-rs` to work it purges your DB data so it doesn't seem you can run a replica set with your old db data without saving it somewhere and copying it back. It also seems you have to turn your homebrew mongo off. I'm not really sure what I'm talking about but this is how I got it to work.

I set up `run-rs` and had to reseed my dev DB.

Here's how I set up the local replica set:

1. Turned off `mongo-community`:

```
$ brew services stop mongodb-community
```

2. Installed and ran `run-rs` using my [data directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827915/location-of-the-mongodb-database-on-mac) (`'/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb'`) and my mongo version (`5.0.6`). Mongo Compass gave me an error when I ran `run-rs --mongod` instead of `run-rs 5.0.6` even though the version was 5.0.6 in both.

```
$ npm install run-rs -g
$ run-rs 5.0.6 --dbpath '/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb' 

# if you don't want to purge the database add the flag --keep
```

Then I ran my seed file and populated a new db at the uri: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wtdev-local?replicaSet=rs`

Make sure to add `replicaSet=rs` to your URI.

**NOTE**

I kept having issues from running `run-rs` in the past incorrectly or some other instance of mongo, and then trying to run mongo again while the old one was still running. My terminal would tell me mongo was already running on port 27017. Whenever this happened, I found the PID and killed any mongo PID's.

```
$ ps wuax | grep mongo

$ kill (pid number)
```

Comment: Hi Dashiell. Thanks for this answer. Following your steps, I turned off mongo-community and tried running "run-rs 5.0.4 --dbpath '/usr/local/var/mongodb' --keep"  (I got version from 'mongo --version' and dbpath from /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf.) I could connect no problem, but the database was empty. I thought supplying dbpath (and --keep) would tell MondoDB to use my existing database. Is that not right? Thanks!

Comment: I see what happened now. It created the primary and secondary instances in three folders  at /usr/local/var/mongodb: 27017, 27018, 27019, completely ignoring my current database at /usr/local/var/mongodb! Is it possible to switch the primary from 27017 to the main /usr/local/var/mongodb, or should I just figure out how to back up the current database and restore it to 27017? Thanks again.