# I'm getting this error when starting mongo daemon it says I didnt create a /data/db directory but created one and also set that as db path

Tags: mongodb

```
    {"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.133+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.137+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.137+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.138+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":25579,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"venkatasridharsais-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.138+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.138+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.5.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.138+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

I tried changing the db path. but for that one single time it worked but if I try executing the `mongod` command again failed with same error message again.
**any fixes would really help.**

Comment: How are you starting the mongod service?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043090/3027266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line say it all:

```
 {"t":{"$date":"2021-06-29T00:04:22.139+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
```

Check your sintax , or add you config file or the command line you use to start the mongod service...

Comment: the command is being executed properly for once when I'm setting the db path. and once I terminate it and then redo the ```mongod``` command the same result. I think some other config file is overwriting the dbpath.