# Recovering a replicaSet from a single AMI without full resync

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, replicaset

I have an AWS AMI backup of a single instance of a replicaSet. I would like to recover the full replicaSet. The replicaSet was configured with 3 hosts (db1.mydomain.com, db2.mydomain.com, db3.mydomain.com)

What I tried:

1. Launch 3 instances from that one AMI
2. Point Route53 CNAMES db[1,2,3].mydomain.com to the newly created instances

My assumption was, since they all start from the same point in time, and are already part of a replicaSet and can see each other, they would just find each other, elect a primary and start working, but that doesn't happen, what I get is:

```
mongo -u <login> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase admin
my-rs:OTHER> rs.status()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
    "code" : 93,
    "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig"
}
```

What does work:

1. Stop mongod

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

2. Connect directly to the DB on each

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /data &
echo -e "use local\ndb.dropDatabase()" | mongo
sudo killall -9 mongod
sudo chown mongod:mongod -R /data
sudo chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo rm /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo service mongod restart
```

3. Connect to one of them and re-create the replicaSet()

```
mongo -u <login> -p <password> db1.mydomain.com --authenticationDatabase admin
mongo> rs.initiate({_id: "my-rs", members: [{_id: 0, host: "db1.mydomain.com:27017"}, {_id: 1, host: "db2.mydomain.com:27017"}, {_id: 2, host: "db3.mydomain.com:27017"}]})
```

This works, but it looks like db2 and db3 are stuck in STARTUP2 for a few hours. It feels like they are syncing to db1 from scratch.

Is there any way that I can revive that replicaSet without dropping the local database, recreating a replicaSet and doing a full resync.

Comment: `kill -9` is certainly not a good idea. Use `service mongod stop` or `db.shutdownServer()`, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.shutdownServer/ You could also use mongo shell like this: `mongo --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("local").dropDatabase()'`

Comment: `mongod --dbpath /data` could be different to `service mongod start` Most likely the mongod service reads the config file and in there might have set a different `dbPath`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090

Comment: Have a look at [Restore a Replica Set from MongoDB Backups](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/) MongoDB provides two options for restoring secondary members of a replica set: [Manually copy the database files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/#std-label-restore-rs-copy-db-files) or [Allow initial sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/#std-label-restore-rs-initial-sync)