# Why am i getting this error when trying to install mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

```
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/mongodb-community
```

I am trying to install MongoDB community but I keep getting this error where it gives me an error saying I don't have a directory named mongodb-community when such a directory already exists.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry! Can you help me though?

Comment: Did you install as root?

Comment: Yes i did. I think ive solved it @WernfriedDomscheit. But im still facing some issues.

Comment: MongoDB shell version v5.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1

Comment: That's a typical error when MongoDB is not started. Did you start the service?

Comment: I think i did.  I used this : brew services start mongodb-community@5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else ran into the same problem:

Solution i: `sudo brew services start mongodb-community`

Solution ii:
`cd Desktop`
`mkdir dbs`
`cd dbs`
 `mongod --dbpath .`

Comment: These two solutions are quite different! When you start the mongodb service then it reads the configuration file, typically `/etc/mongod.conf` (for Linux). The second one does not read any config file. Thus, the behavior can be very different. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090