# I shut down mongodb server and now I can't start it again with mongod

Tags: mongodb

I use db.shutdownServer() and now want to start it again using mongod, but now it doesn't work, this is the logs

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.545-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.548-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.548-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.548-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.549-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.549-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.549-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.549-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.550-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":15921,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"s-Vostro-3400"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.550-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.550-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.550-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-05T08:11:38.551-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

looks like there is not /data/db folder, but I don't want to lose the previous info, what can I do?

Comment: Check that the `/data/db` folder exists, if not, just create it. The log shows: `/data/db not found`,

Comment: How did you start the MongoDB before? Maybe try `systemctl start mongod` or similar.

Comment: @MauricioContreras I already create it and prints the same error+

Comment: Look for "NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found" in your logs. Your data directory is somehow missing. Try mongod --dbpath=<what i assume to be /data/db> and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `mongod` then MongoDB process is started with default parameters, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/

However, when you run `systemctl start mongod` then systemd loads service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` (check with `systemctl status mongod`). When you check this service file then you see that process is started as `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`, i.e. it uses the config file `/etc/mongod.conf`.

The settings in this config file can be different than mongod default parameters, see [What is the default database path for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090)

Note, if you like to customize your Mongo service, then you should not edit service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` directly. Instead, make a copy to `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` and modify this copy according to your preferences. Otherwise when you upgrade MongoDB, the installer may revert `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` file to default values.

Folders in this answer apply to Redhat Linux, they may be different on Ubuntu. Have a look at your system documentation.

Answer (score -1):

first run:

```
sudo brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

Then run:

```
sudo brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```