# Mongodb database removed in Debian

Tags: mongodb, format, debian

I installed mongodb database following this guide
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/
It worked a few hours or more.
Suddenly 2 days later, I found there is no collection at all.
I checked mongodb status, and its still active.

[image]

Connection has no problem, but only there is no collection I created before.
Db is saved in default path.

[image]

I am not sure what to do. Please help me.

Comment: How do you know the data is not there? Did you checked other databases inside same server?

Comment: I checked with mongodb compass and another way is website login.
I created a user and used to login, but when I tried login with that user, api return user not found error.

Comment: try from shell: mongo --port XXXX --host YYYY test --authenticationDatabase=admin -u youruser -p password

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: How did you start the database? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090

Comment: I started by this command `systemctl start mongodb`