# MongoDB installation error in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-22.04

While i am trying to install MongoDB in my system following the [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), everything is going fine but when i try to start the server there is some error :[Image of error showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJUwb.png)

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Have a look at the mongod logfile, typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. Most likely you did not create the folder for `dpPath` (default `/var/lib/mongodb`, see [What is the default database path for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090)) and granted permissions to it.

Answer (score -2):

Follow this step

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libssl1.1

echo "* Installing Mongod..."
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod status
```