# Can't Connect Mongodb to a local server showing error{MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed}

Tags: mongodb, server, nosql

i am using nodejs for backend and so to connect with database i tried with MOngoDB 7.0 (this is my first time using database) but i saw many solution videos and articles of this error. but cant find any useful for me
please help me with this? Tried to start from services also no way. error images are uploaded

- WHEN I USING TO CONNECT VIA `MONGOSH.EXE`
  [mongosh.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phf9a.png)
- WHEN I USING TO START FROM SERVICES
  [services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwx8.png)

As per above i tried these two methods no way it is not connecting please help me with a solution

**I FOUND ONE THING**

-When i installed MongoDB and open mongodb/server/7.0/data i didnt find anything there

-but when i installed it on my friend's system it worked and when i looked in mongodb/server/7.0/data there are many files

so why when i installed the data folder empty

**when command in cmd mongod a error attempted**

{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-24T07:47:59.775+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"setup bind :: caused by :: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."}}}

and at last it showing {"exitCode":48}}

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Did you check the MongoDB logfile? The logfile location is specified in the config file. The config file you should see in the service properties.

Comment: In the second "WHEN I USING TO CONNECT VIA CMD" you don't try to connect to the database, you try to start the MongoDB database service. That's something different.

Comment: ok next time i will dont post screenshot i will use formatted text

Comment: i didnt understand (The config file you should see in the service properties) can you explain it

Comment: Have a look at the properties in service manager. Or run `sc qc "MongoDB Server (MongoDB)"` - or whatever the exact service name is.

Comment: it showing like this

Comment: SERVICE_NAME: MongoDB
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.cfg" --service
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : MongoDB Server (MongoDB)
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

Comment: Please update your question with such additional information instead of putting it into a comment. Have a look at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.cfg`, there you will find [systemLog.path](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-systemLog.path) Have a look at this logfile, it should show the reason for your problem. You an also try to start the MongoDB directly with `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.cfg"`

Comment: any update on my edited question please

Comment: From the error it could be, that the service is already running. Note, when you run just `mongod` then data is stored at `C:\data\db`. In the config file you have a different path, see [What is the default database path for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090). And again, do you see anything in the logfile?