# MongoDB Server failed to start

Tags: mongodb, windows

While I was installing **mongodb.msi**, but these issue occurred.
I attached the below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5swTr.png)

I tried to find resolution, but still couldn't find anywhere.
Please help me. thanks in advance.

I thought it may works well after I changed the status of mongodb in `serrvices.msc`.
But the result was same.

I need to solve this issue quickly before I join the pair-programming.

Comment: If you just uninstalled MongoDB, then restart your machine because the 'service' from the previous installation doesn't get removed until then. Also, since this question is not about a programming issue, it's not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Check the logfile. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528061/cant-connect-mongodb-to-a-local-server-showing-errormongoserverselectionerror to see where to find it (follow the **comments** of the question).

Comment: Good question, Same problem occurred.