# Where is the MongoDB Data?

Tags: mongodb

This is more of a general question about how MongoDB works.

But I've been using MongoDB for a while and everything seems to be working for me. The part that currently confuses me, though, is that when I visit the directory where the MongoDB data is saved (I'm using the default `data/db`) the directory is empty. The data is being persisted, I'm just confused - why does the directory appears empty on my computer?

I'm on Windows, if that's worth anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute :

```
  db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.storage.dbPath
```

from inside the mongo process and find what the dbPath startup parameter show to find where your data is saved

or alternatively check from the config file in windows:

```
 <install directory>/bin/mongod.cfg
```

Comment: Hmm. That's an interesting command, looks useful for learning more. Unfortunately there weren't any parameters named `dbPath` in the output.

Comment: my mistake , check again my answer , the correct command is db.serverCmdLineOpts()

Comment: btw just found this question is already answered in details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247474/how-can-i-tell-where-mongodb-is-storing-data-its-not-in-the-default-data-db

Answer (score 1):

`dbPath` can be confusing.

When you run mongod without `--dbpath` option or unset it in config file then it defaults to `\data\db`

However, when you use the default config files which comes along the installation then the `dpPath` is different (I don't remember by heart which). So you should really check path with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` as suggested by R2D2

I know, for Linux the default `dbPath` is `/data/db` but the pre-installed config file `/etc/mongod.conf` has set `/var/lib/mongo`