# Local Database File Associated with .dwg File

Tags: mongodb, autocad-plugin

I am planning on building an AutoCAD extension application that will require custom data be stored outside of the standard .dwg file for AutoCAD drawings. I would like there to be a local file that this custom data is stored in so that the data can be read into AutoCAD or saved from AutoCAD while offline. I have been imagining that each .dwg file would have it’s own separate database file associated with it, but I am also open to the idea of having a single data file locally stored in order to allow for offline reading/writing of my custom data. Does MongoDB support this type of local data storage? There will be a cloud-based database where the data can be read from/written to, but I want there to be a local storage system to allow for offline read/write and also improved speed. I am just a bit confused about this because most resources online seem to address cloud storage and I am having a hard time understanding how to use MongoDB to implement a reliable local storage system.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to install the MongoDB Community Server edition locally on your machine.
You can download the installer [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community).
Installation instructions can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/).
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247474/how-can-i-tell-where-mongodb-is-storing-data-its-not-in-the-default-data-db) addresses where the data is stored. Basically it's one storage location per machine (where you can put all your databases).
You may need a GUI interface to browse all your databases. The community edition installer will prompt you to install Compass. I'm using a different software called Robo 3T for that.
Something like [nedb-promises](https://github.com/bajankristof/nedb-promises) may be of interest for creating a database local to the application.
(I've also been looking into how to use MongoDB locally, so the above is a summary of what I've found so far.)

Comment: I am on the same page as you completed for setting up development databases. However, whenever I have made apps that use MongoDB, you always eventually move the database to the cloud. My use case is requires a fully local setup for an application. Specifically, the server is running locally while the app is running, and is accessing local data. So, do you think it is possible to install mongodb community server as a requirement for my application, and then programmatically setup and run the server as the application runs?

Comment: During development I know how to run the MongoDB server from the terminal and access local data with Robo 3T. I am trying to determine whether or not it is possible/recommended to programmatically run the MongoDB server as a dependency for my AutoCAD add-in as it runs on the user's machine in order to manage local data storage for the add-in.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on your question. It seems you already have MongoDB running locally. What do you mean by "programmatically setup" or "programmatically run the MongoDB server"? Do you want to automate the installation of the MongoDB community server when your AutoCAD add-in is installed? I don't know how to do that. Are you asking if it's LEGALLY possible to bundle the community server edition with your add-in? Check this [link](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10293/can-i-freely-redistribute-mongodb-community-msi-installer-with-proprietary-soft).

Comment: Yes to your second to last question: "Do you want to automate the installation of the MongoDB community server when your AutoCAD add-in is installed?" But installation is only part of my question, because you also have to configure and then run the MongoDB server after it has been installed on the end-user's machine. I am wondering whether it is possible/recommended to do this with the MongoDB server in order to manage local data for my add-in on the user's machine.